# Is there a widely used way to write "any IP address" as a string?

Tags: sockets, ip, ipv6

I've seen APIs that use "*" and "::" (for IPv6) to mean "any address" (i.e. `INADDR_ANY`) when binding a socket. I've also seen APIs that use "" or "0.0.0.0" to mean the same. Is there a widely use standard for writing "any address" as a string?

Comment: An IPv6 socket can connect to IPv4 via [address mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses), thus `in6addr_any` and `::0` would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the two ways. Sadly there isn't one that works for both IPv4 and IPv6. When binding a socket you should certainly use INADDR_ANY.

Answer (score -1):

It's such a good idea, that there's more than one widely used way to write that. Isn't programming fun?